# Diagnose "Not enough storage is available to process this command" exception

Tags: c#, windows, .net

What information should I capture when my file copy process intermittantly fails with a "System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command." exception?

The process has been running successfully for years, but over the last week has been failing intermittantly.  The IT crew assures me that nothing has changed in the server environment.

The file copying service, a .Net 3.5 Windows Service, is a Console Application built for the "Any CPU" platform, running under the identity of a domain user on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit machine.  It copies files from a source share to a destination share.

The source share is on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit SP1 machine.

The destination share is on a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise 32-bit SP2 machine.  It has over over a terabyte of free space, and the files being copied are small pdfs (most about 18k).

The line of code that copies the file is:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("\\SourceShare\folder\file.pdf", "\\DestinationShare\folder\file.pdf", true);
```

When this call fails with the "System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command." exception, what environmental information should I capture that would help me diagnose the problem?

P.S. Here are some numbers captured in the catch block during a typical exception.  See anything which would hint at the cause of a "not enough storage" error?

```
nonpagedSystemMemorySize64 = 43 kb 
pagedMemorySize64 = 330,680 kb 
pagedSystemMemorySize64 = 248 kb 
peakPagedMemorySize64 = 449,196 kb 
peakVirtualMemorySize64 = 825,024 kb 
peakWorkingSet64 = 442,792 kb 
privateMemorySize64 = 330,680 kb 
virtualMemorySize64 = 818,048 kb 
workingSet64 = 324,360 kb 
totalProcessorTime = 00:11:05.3442650 
userProcessorTime = 00:08:14.1019673 
privilegedProcessorTime = 00:02:51.2422977 
handleCount = 316 
gcTotalMemory = 266,652 kb
```

Comment: "The IT crew assures me that nothing has changed in the server environment." don't instantly assume they are right. Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: I assume nothing, but alas I have no access to either the source or destination machines.  My sole source of information is whatever I can gather when the exception happens.  Thus my question.  In any case the problem is intermittent; most of the file copies succeed.

Comment: Could the computer where the code is executing be running out of space?

Comment: Good question.  How would you capture that at runtime when the exception is logged?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have the free space on your server and you are absolutely sure that you have the right permissions, then I suggest you to check IRP Stacksize.

This might occur due to high NonPagedPool and PagedPool utilization.

Article shows how to change IRPStack size for Windows Server 2003 and below:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285089

That should also work for Windows Server 2008 but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you know what information I would need to capture when logging the exception to diagnose that IRP Stacksize is the problem?

Comment: @TomRegan https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/general/troubleshooting-nonpaged-and-paged-pool-errors-in-windows/ . This is shows you how to troubleshoot and plus how to check.